# Code stuck at ".thumb_func .weak HardFault_HandlerHardFault_Handler" on NRF52840 using PCA10056

Tags: handler, nrf52, weak, nrf52840

I'm working on a project using an NRF52840 microcontroller and the PCA10056 development board. When I debug my code, it gets stuck at the following line:

.thumb_func
.weak HardFault_Handler
HardFault_Handler:
b

when i build the project i get no eror